# How does Linux kernel create /dev/mtdx nodes?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

An example of the mtd partition table is in arch/arm/mach-omap2/board-omap3beagle.c for the beagleboard http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-omap2/board-omap3beagle.c

```
static struct mtd_partition omap3beagle_nand_partitions[] = {
/* All the partition sizes are listed in terms of NAND block size */
{
    .name       = "X-Loader",
    .offset     = 0,
    .size       = 4 * NAND_BLOCK_SIZE,
    .mask_flags = MTD_WRITEABLE,    /* force read-only */
},
{
    .name       = "U-Boot",
    .offset     = MTDPART_OFS_APPEND,   /* Offset = 0x80000 */
    .size       = 15 * NAND_BLOCK_SIZE,
    .mask_flags = MTD_WRITEABLE,    /* force read-only */
},
{
    .name       = "U-Boot Env",
    .offset     = MTDPART_OFS_APPEND,   /* Offset = 0x260000 */
    .size       = 1 * NAND_BLOCK_SIZE,
},
{
    .name       = "Kernel",
    .offset     = MTDPART_OFS_APPEND,   /* Offset = 0x280000 */
    .size       = 32 * NAND_BLOCK_SIZE,
},
{
    .name       = "File System",
    .offset     = MTDPART_OFS_APPEND,   /* Offset = 0x680000 */
    .size       = MTDPART_SIZ_FULL,
},
};
```

Another link states this:
http://landley.net/kdocs/Documentation/DocBook/xhtml-nochunks/mtdnand.html
In this link Nand flash driver `board_init` function passes the `mtd_partition structure` is passed to
`add_mtd_partitions(board_mtd, partition_info, NUM_PARTITIONS);` function in file `mtdcore.c` file.

If I am right then does the `mtdcores.c` file create the mtd partitions?

Now I have two questions:

1> If I am right, then the `omap3_beagle_init` function in file /board-omap3beagle.c will call the `omap_nand_flash_init` function this will initialize the NAND & create /dev/mdtx nodes.

If I am not right then what creates the /dev/mtd0 nodes? Does the kernel create it or the NAND driver?

2> Also, is the `omap3_beagle_init` function the first function called by the kernel? Which file in the linux kernel is it called from?

Comment: Please any one who can suggest on this post ..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/ There are multiples ways the device files can be created. Usually, they are now created using `devtmpfs` which is part of the kernel. When a driver or a subsystem registers a new device, `devtmpfs_create_node` is called This wakes up a thread that will add the device node to the `devtmpfs` filesystem.

If your kernel is not using `devtmpfs`, then you have to create those device files manually, using `mknod`. Also `mdev` is also a tool that can create device file. Finally, `udev` used to create device files but now relies on `devtmpfs`.

2/ `omap3_beagle_init` is definitively not the first function called by the kernel. After decompressing itself, the entry point is `start_kernel` in [init/main.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L497). This is architecture independent.
`omap3_beagle_init` is called from the `customize_machine` arch_initcall in [arch/arm/kernel/setup.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c#L823)

Comment: Thanks for replying ... If mtd partition is defined statically in struct mtd_partition then how will kernel create /dev/mtdx nodes... because udev is still not running .. also which part of kernel will call devtmpfs_create_node for creating /dev/mtdx nodes ..?

Comment: The mtd subsystem does. `add_mtd_partitions` -> `add_mtd_device` -> `device_register` -> `device_add` -> `devtmpfs_create_node`

Comment: One last point from my side devtmpfs creates tmpfs file system which can be mounted at /dev directory once rootfs is mounted ... so this means embedded system do not need udev or mdev demons .. right ?

Comment: You may still need udev or mdev to handl hotplug events and for example change permissions on the device files.